# Подключение Delphi dll к C# проекту

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

Есть библиотека CheckUfa.dll
В справке разработчика написано, что подключать, нужные мне функции, к Delphi проекту вот так:

```
function CheckFile(fname,reportName,typRep:PChar;fox:integer):integer; StdCall;
function CheckFile2(fname,typRep:PChar;Precheck:integer):WideString; StdCall;
function CheckFile3(fname,reportName,typRep:PChar;fox:integer):wideString; StdCall;
```

Менял LPStr, LPWStr. Убирал и ставил разные MarshalAs. IntPtr. Ничего.

Один из примеров того, что пробовал (касаемо CheckFile2):

```
[DllImport(@"D:\CheckUfa.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern IntPtr CheckFile2(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            StringBuilder fname,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            StringBuilder typRep,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
            int Precheck);

...
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(...
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(...

return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(CheckFile2(sb1, sb2, 0));
...
```

Comment: Если создавалось в старой (до 2009) версии Delphi, то PChar = PAnsiChar. Как это на C# - увы, не знаю. Ну и - функция из dll возвращает же WideString, а не PWideChar, почему тип возвращаемого параметра - LPWstr (емнип, это pointer to wide string, т.е. PWideChar), т.е тип не соответствует. Но могу и ошибаться :)

Comment: через референсы не подключается

Comment: Вот здесь есть пример как это делать: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208928/using-delphi-dll-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, за помощь.

Подведу итог.
Компилятор в Delphi преобразует функцию в процедуру. Именно поэтому в C# нужно использовать void, и out переменную result.

PChar успешно получилось импортировать только в IntPtr, остальные типы были с ошибками.

Нужная мне функция CheckFile2 в тоге заработала вот так:

```
[DllImport(@"D:\CheckPfr\CheckUfa.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "#2")]

        public static extern void CheckFile2(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            out string result,
            IntPtr fname,
            IntPtr typRep,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
            int Precheck);
```

Обратите внимание, что по своей сути fname это строка, поэтому вызывая CheckFile2 я использовал Marshal

```
CheckFile2(out result, Marshal.StringToBSTR(fname), Marshal.StringToBSTR(typRep), 0);
```

Comment: Такая ситуация только с возвратом `WideString`, простые типы и указатели должны возвращаться как положено.